# SignalR with mvc 5 application

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr, signalr-hub

I am very new with signalR. In my asp.net mvc 5 project I need to use signalR. But I am failing to do that. Even I don't where I am doing wrong because I am new here. How can I resolve this? Here is my code below:

Hub:

```
[HubName("statusLog")]
public class StatusLogHub : Hub
{
    //public void Hello()
    //{
    //    Clients.All.hello();
    //}
    [HubMethodName("sendExportStatus")]
    public static void SendExportStatus()
    {
        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<StatusLogHub>();
        context.Clients.All.updateStatus();
    }
}
```

controller:

```
public ActionResult GetExportStatus()
    {
        EmailStatusLogRepository objEmailStatusRepository = new EmailStatusLogRepository();
        return PartialView("_exportedReportList", objEmailStatusRepository.GetExportStatus());
    }
```

View:

```
$("#btnEmail").click(function () {          
        tinyMCE.triggerSave(true, true);
        $('#emailform').submit();            
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Email")',
            type: "POST",
            data: $('#emailform').serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true,
           //SignalR
            success: function () {
                // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
                var notifications = $.connection.statusLog;

                notifications.client.updateStatus = function () {
                    getExportStatus()

                };
                // Start the connection.
                $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                    alert("connection started")
                    getExportStatus();
                }).fail(function (e) {
                    alert(e);
                });
            }

        });
        function getExportStatus() {
            var tbl = $('#statusTable');
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetExportStatus")',
                contentType: 'application/html ; charset:utf-8',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'html'
            }).success(function (result) {
                tbl.empty().append(result);
            }).error(function () {

            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: are you able to connect with your hub?

Comment: Yes I'm able to connect with my hub

Comment: check your console and verify that you not getting any errors with getExportStatus() method, it seems that you are using HTML datatype while returning PartialView from controller.

Comment: exactly what you guess. getExportStatus() method is giving the error. can you please tell me what can I do? or any kind of example that will be helpful for me. I already told that I am totally new here and last of all thanks a lot for  your response @cracker

Comment: replace your return with return Json(new { Message = "ok" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); and check if you are getting response.

Comment: thanks a lot @cracker. But can you please tell me how I use getExportStatus() method to fetch data from server and put it on the $.connection.hub.start() method .

Comment: very good example is here, http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc